# Handling errors with the RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

How to get the errors returned when calling a RESTAdapter method (by example deleteRecord).

I can see this code in the sources but I do not clearly understand.

Is there a sample code available providing error handling management with ember-model RESTAdapter ?

```
settings.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
      };
```

Comment: I believe most, if not all, methods return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ember Documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.Promise.html) describes promises and how to handle them.